# Responsive web design by using css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am going to make a website that is using responsive design. I read some information about css media query. What I wanna do is that the layout of my webpage should looks difference by using different devices (like PC, tablets or smartphones).

If I use media query to determine the device by using the width of the screen (in pixel), I always worry about if there will be a new device using a extremely high ppi screen. That device may threat as tablet or something like PC?

Another solution that is using the user agent to determine the device category by using userAgent. There's also a problem is that if the device not interpret the javascript fine then the page maybe broken.

Any great solution that can solve my worries above? Or Which solution is better?

Or I misunderstand the method of using media query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CSS is the way to go, and you can always provide fallback for browsers that don't support media queries using a js plugin like [css3mediaqueries.js](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/), but relying on JS solely to make your website responsive is a risk because you can't tell for sure if the user will have Javascript enabled, and when it's *not* enabled it's not going to be responsive anymore.

Also, it's considered best practice now to use **em** values for media queries instead of pixels to make sure your website always scales right. More on this topic in [this article](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/).

Another tip is that you determine the media query values according to your content's best break points instead of device dimensions, that way you also make sure your content will always look right no matter how many new devices are made.

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

id' personally use CSS and set min-width and max-width. Most responsive designs now days use CSS. This way if there is a new device on the market it will just adjust according to it's screen size.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) { }
@media screen and (min-width:481px) { ) etc... etccc....
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Twtitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) over using CSS3 media queries for such various devices.

Comment: bootstrap does use css3 media queries.

Comment: Sure it does, but we don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use **media queries** in CSS.
Just write the **queries** after the default CSS...

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { **write here only the elements that must change de code for responsive performance** }

```
.logo {
width: 200px;
height: 80px;
background: url... ;
background-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.logo {
width: 150px;
height: 60px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

**Don't forget to insert the viewport code into the head/HTML.**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=false" />
```

Comment: Please don't include `maximum-scale=1` and `user-scalable=false` unless you have a very good reason for doing so. Terribly hostile to users.

Comment: I include maximum-scale=1 and user-scalable=false to disable the mobile zoom for responsive websites and I've never had any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try jRWD, a JavaScript-only module I designed recently. It uses 12 lines of pure JavaScript and 2 small helper functions. It's available on GitHub, at https://github.com/BlackMagic/jRWD.

If you want to see jRWD in action, visit http://ieee-qld.org. Make sure you inspect the source code. Minimal JavaScript, minimal CSS stylesheet. No jQuery either.

Comment: This answer seems outdated. I did not found any traces of jRWD in the listed website.